# Getting `Abort trap: 6` Error During `import cv2` on Python 3.10 with macOS ARM64

Tags: python, macos, opencv

Getting the following `Abort trap: 6` error while doing `import cv2` on Python 3.10 with macOS ARM64.

I tried using lower version of opencv-python (4.6.0.66) and latest version but still doesn't work. I've also tried some of the fixes such as using different Terminal and symlink `libssl.dylib` and `libcrypto.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib`.

```
> python
Python 3.10.11 (main, May 22 2023, 00:42:58) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Modules/gcmodule.c:115: gc_decref: Assertion "gc_get_refs(g) > 0" failed: refcount is too small
Enable tracemalloc to get the memory block allocation traceback

object address  : 0x105a54010
object refcount : 8
object type     : 0x1056e3ab8
object type name: type
object repr     : <class 'cv2.utils.nested.ExportClassName'>

Fatal Python error: _PyObject_AssertFailed: _PyObject_AssertFailed
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00000001fce51e00 (most recent call first):
Garbage-collecting
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1176 in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571 in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 674 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050 in _gcd_import
File "/opt/python/3.10.11/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126 in import_module
File "/Users/alpha/Python/pv310-3di/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153 in bootstrap
File "/Users/alpha/Python/pv310-3di/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181 in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883 in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>

Extension modules: numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator (total: 13)
Abort trap: 6
>
```

Comment: v4.6 is not the latest release. try again with _current_ release, which is v4.7. no issues are accepted on outdated versions. if the issue was fixed since then, you're only causing everyone extra work

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, i tried it with the current latest version of 4.7.0.72, but same issue occurs. The article I found below was helpful in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this article below from the OpenCV Forum:

[Opencv causes debug-enabled python interpreter to abort with a refcount error](https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-causes-debug-enabled-python-interpreter-to-abort-with-a-refcount-error/12301)

It seem like (at least on macOS from my perspective) compiling Python with the

`--with-pydebug`

flag causes the error, I recompile Python without the flag, it seem to be working fine for now...